# Open a new (empty) tab with JavaScript on click and add URL after

Tags: javascript

I'm making a product category page similar to this one https://www.stylight.se/Skor/Herr/. I want to be able to send visitors to a different page upon clicking on a product, and the page should open in a new tab (just like on the page I've linked).

However, when I try to replicate that with Ajax I get a one second delay between clicking on the product and the tab actually opening, due to the time it takes to query my database for the URL for the product clicked.

I notice that on the page I linked to, the tab opens instantly with "about:blank", and only seems to redirect to the URL in question after that.

I'm currently doing window.open(response) with the response from the ajax call.

Is it possible to open a new tab first and then redirect that tab to a new URL, and if so, how can it be done with javascript? Alternatively - how does the aforementioned page accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value returned by `window.open`, as it is a reference to the opened window object.

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.location.href = 'https://google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

They use this code

```js
static goToUrlBlank(url) {
  if (url) {
    let newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');

    if (newWindow !== undefined && newWindow !== null) {
      newWindow.focus();
    } else {
      // fallback for browser blocking the opening in a new tab
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  }
}
```