# Achieving Page Redirection in Outlook Add-in Action

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, manifest, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've created an Outlook add-in. I have only a manifest that I deploy via Azure. I have this part:

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
       <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>
```

But I would like for the action instead of displaying in a web view, it opens a new page of edge. Can you help me ? Tanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ribbon commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) where you declare such actions don't allow opening new web browser tabs by default. There are two types of add-in commands, based on the kind of action that the command triggers.

- `Task pane commands`: The button or menu item opens the add-in's task pane. You add this kind of add-in command with markup in the manifest. The "code behind" the command is provided by Office.
- `Function commands`: The button or menu item runs any arbitrary JavaScript. The code almost always calls APIs in the Office JavaScript Library, but it doesn't have to. This type of add-in typically displays no UI other than the button or menu item itself. Note the following about function commands:

  - The function that is triggered can call the `displayDialogAsync` method to show a dialog, which is a good way to display an error, show progress, or prompt for input from the user. If the add-in is configured to use a shared runtime, the function can also call the showAsTaskpane method.
  - The runtime in which the function command runs is a full browser-based runtime. It can render HTML and call out to the Internet to send or get data.

You may try using JS scripts for opening a new blank tab like described on the [Open a new (empty) tab with JavaScript on click and add URL after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465843/open-a-new-empty-tab-with-javascript-on-click-and-add-url-after) page. But you need to keep in mind that Office web add-ins are run on different platforms and in desktop applications that don't have any web browser visible by default.

So, I'd suggest opening a dialog window or use a task pane to navigate to another URL.